# Windows-RT and WinRT synonym request

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

I was asking a question about Windows 8 and Windows RT and I looked for tags starting in Windows that could be RT, but found none. Only to later have the tag of WinRT added later.

I think there should be a synonym of WinRT <- WindowsRT or Windows-RT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft has made another naming blunder here.  [WinRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime) is *not* the same thing as [Windows RT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_RT).  If there's any tag changing to be proposed, it should be to alias [winrt](/questions/tagged/winrt) to [windows-runtime](/questions/tagged/windows-runtime), which does not currently exist.

Comment: That is terrible... But if that is the case, then there should be a separate Windows-RT tag?

Comment: Not until there are actually questions about Windows RT that are on topic for SO.  There have been no public beta/RCs of RT yet, only of the x86-based Windows 8.  Given that RT is exclusively intended for ARM tablets and will probably only be licensed to OEMs, I doubt that we're going to see Windows RT questions any time soon.  Further, given that targeting the Windows Runtime will allow your application to run on both Windows 8 and Windows RT, and given that Windows RT is "just" Windows 8 on ARM, I'm not sure we'll ever really need a tag for it.  Time will tell.